Merge rows in PySpark DataFrame based on partial overlapping values in a column
I would like to merge rows in PySpark DataFrame based on partial overlapping values in a column. Here's a simplified example:
| values    | sources        |
| --------- | -------------- |
| [a, b]    | [s1, s2, s3]   |
| [b, c, d] | [s5, s1]       |
| [x, y]    | [s7]           |

In this example, since row 1 and 2 share one of the same sources, s1, then merge the values, And [x, y] doesn't share sources with others so leave them alone. So the expected output would be something like:
| values       | sources         |
| ------------ | --------------- |
| [a, b, c, d] | [s1, s2, s3, s5]|
| [x, y]       | [s7]            |

I started by exploding the sources column to the following but not sure how to go from there. Thank you in advance!
exploded_df = df.select(
    col("values").alias("values"),
    explode(col("sources")).alias("source")
).select(
    col("values"),
    col("source")
)

| values   | sources        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| [a, b]   | s1             |
| [a, b]   | s2             |
| [a, b]   | s3             |
| [b, c, d]| s5             |
| [b, c, d]| s1             |
| [x, y]   | s7             |


After exploding the dataframe, you need to group by your dataframe by values column. To avoid duplication you need to use collect_set function in the group by aggregation.After grouping and collecting unique sources, you need to select the flattened values and the distinct sources. You can do it this way:
from pyspark.sql.functions import collect_set, flatten, array_distinct

exploded_df = df.select(
    col("values").alias("values"),
    explode(col("sources")).alias("sources")
)

result_df = exploded_df.groupBy("values") \
                        .agg(collect_set("sources").alias("sources")) \
                        .select(
                            flatten(collect_set("values")).alias("values"),
                            array_distinct("sources").alias("sources")
                        )

result_df.show(truncate=False)


This is impossible without a loop. Let's break it down:

If you have a situation like in your example where you only have distinct pairs of rows with overlapping values you could it by a self join on F.arrays_overlap condition, followed by some further manipulations:

df = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    (['a','b'], ['s1', 's2', 's3']),
    (['b', 'c', 'd'], ['s5', 's1']),
    (['x', 'y'], ['s7'])
], ['values', 'sources'])

df1 = df.toDF(*df.columns)

# Here we prepare the joined df for further split
inter_df = df.join(df1, F.arrays_overlap(df['sources'], df1['sources']))


It looks like that:
inter_df.show()

+---------+------------+---------+------------+
|   values|     sources|   values|     sources|
+---------+------------+---------+------------+
|   [a, b]|[s1, s2, s3]|   [a, b]|[s1, s2, s3]|
|   [a, b]|[s1, s2, s3]|[b, c, d]|    [s5, s1]|
|[b, c, d]|    [s5, s1]|   [a, b]|[s1, s2, s3]|
|[b, c, d]|    [s5, s1]|[b, c, d]|    [s5, s1]|
|   [x, y]|        [s7]|   [x, y]|        [s7]|
+---------+------------+---------+------------+

Now we need to separate overlapping rows from the non-overlapping ones:
non_overlapping_df = inter_df.withColumn('cnt', F.count('*').over(w)).filter(F.col('cnt') == 1).\
    select(df['values'], df['sources'])
non_overlapping_df.show()

+------+-------+
|values|sources|
+------+-------+
|[x, y]|   [s7]|
+------+-------+

overlapping_df = inter_df.filter(df['sources'] != df1['sources']).\
    withColumn('new_values', F.array_union(df['values'], df1['values'])).\
    withColumn('new_sources', F.array_sort(F.array_union(df['sources'], df1['sources']))).\
    select(F.col('new_values').alias('values'), F.col('new_sources').alias('sources')).dropDuplicates(['sources'])
overlapping_df.show()

+------------+----------------+
|      values|         sources|
+------------+----------------+
|[a, b, c, d]|[s1, s2, s3, s5]|
+------------+----------------+


But what if we have more than 2 overlapping rows? For example:

+---------+------------+
|   values|     sources|
+---------+------------+
|   [a, b]|[s1, s2, s3]|
|[b, c, d]|    [s5, s1]|
|   [x, y]|        [s7]|
|   [e, f]|    [s5, s6]|
+---------+------------+

Now we have row number 4 overlapping with the row number 2. It gives us a chain of overlapping rows 1 -> 2 -> 4. Let's try the same approach on the new df.
The non-overlapping part will be the same but the overlapping one will give us the following:
+---------------+----------------+
|         values|         sources|
+---------------+----------------+
|[b, c, d, e, f]|    [s1, s5, s6]|
|   [a, b, c, d]|[s1, s2, s3, s5]|
+---------------+----------------+

Two overlapping rows. So after union of this part with the non-overlapping one you will have a situation where you can repeat the whole process again and merge 2 bigger parts into 1 and finally get the answer. If you have more than 3 overlapping rows - you will need more repeats of the same procedure to finally reduce it. So basically you'll need a loop with a breaking condition on whether there are only rows with distinct sources values.
